# List all LocalConnection channels open in the page

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Is it possible to list all channels initiated by LocalConnections from other SWF files?

I have an embed SWF file that creates a LocalConnection using a random number for the channel, and I would like to get connected to that channel, using another SWF I am building. However, I see no way I can connect to it, unless I know the channel's name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, it's not possible.

If your embed swf is AS3 based you can pass LC name to it when swf is loaded (or listen for the name in event from it, not difference), if it's AS2 the only way to pass variables is to load it with `Loader` by URL (not as embed bytes) and pass param via query, like `"as2file.swf?lcname=_mylcname"`

Comment: Hi! Thank you. The embed SWF could be AS2 or AS3 (it's several of them). All the embed SWF load another SWF from a site that is no longer alive. It loads like "service.swf?listenLC=ms1235125". This is why I am trying to remake "service.swf", and catch that "listenLC" random name. Any ideas here? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I didn't get the problem ) you already get the LC name as _listenLC=ms1235125_ why you can't use it?

Comment: Hi. As I said, the "listenLC" is in the GET query of an SWF that was in a site that doesn't exist anymore (the URL is hardcoded in the embed SWF). The company was closed. Also, while the embed SWF files are hosted in my site, they were developed by others, so I don't have the source. I am trying to re-make the functionality of the non-existent SWF, by communicating with the embed SWF, using the same random channel. Thank you.

Comment: _(the URL is hardcoded in the embed SWF)_ is it an absolute or relative url? You mean _embed_ in html page, not with _Embed_ metatag, right? If you have an ability to substitute that missed service swf I guess URL is relative but in that case you have the LC name from query, if the _URL_ is absolute I don't see any possibility to substitute that _service.swf_ or sniff the LC name from it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The URL is absolute. My fix would be to embed another SWF in the same page, listening to the same channel, so it would somehow do the same functionality of the previous SWF that does not exist anymore. With "embed", I mean with the "object" HTML tag.

Comment: OK, i got it, but I think it's not possible to sniff that LC name in that case.